# Free universe tool monitoring all database

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, oracle

Is there any free tool to monitor most popular databases like Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL. I want to monitor the real time performance of all the above mentioned databases with a single tool like DBEAVER. But DBEAVER does not have real time monitoring facility.
Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Mahendra

Comment: ***One*** tool to monitor all these databases? I doubt that very much.

Comment: Shopping list questions are off-topic for dba.se as they are primarily opinion based and do not necessarily have a definitive correct answer.  See the [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm fond of it, but if you use Nagios, it's rather easy to add some database-related plugins. You could do worse than have a look at:

- [PostgreSQL](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/PostgresQL/check_postgres/details): Very useful. The latest versions are available at [Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres).
- [MySQL](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/MySQL): quite a few are available, make your pick.
- [Oracle](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/Oracle/check_oracle_health/details): but you'd better ask the Oracle experts.
- [MsSQL](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer/check_mssql/details): I'm not using it yet but will test it soon.